# Debug Diag generate large memory dump files

Tags: debugdiag

I configured `Debug Diag` on `Production` where I set a `Crash rule` for a specific `app pool` with action type `Long Stack Trace`. But the problem is it's generating dump file those are very large in size approx `700mb` each. I'm not sure why these files are too large. Is there a way to `truncate` it?

Answer (score 0):

When you use "Log Stack Trace" option, the callstack for the exception will be logged in to a text file (not dump file) that Debug Diagnostic generates for the process to which it is attached to. I am assuming that the dump is getting generated if your process is crashing with a 2nd chance exception (that is, if you didn't change anything else in the default crash rule).

If you look at the name of the dump file, you would be able to identify on what exact condition the dump got generated.